# Bug with pagebrowser when using multiple instances of tt_news

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tt-news

I'am using two tt_news views on a webpage. The LIST mode as a regular List-View of the latest 2 news and the HEADER_LIST mode as a view of the latest 10 news. See it in action [here](http://reiser.it-service-pn.de/news.html).

The problem is when you use the pagebrowser the HEADER_LIST disappears. 
I posted my TYPOSCRIPT Configuration [here](http://pastebin.com/8WtGXc43).

Comment: It seems the problem is known since 2007: http://bugs.typo3.org/view.php?id=5981 but for me in version 3.4.0 (current version) the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't see the HEADER_LIST.
The below typoscript may help you:

```
plugin.tt_news.excludeAlreadyDisplayedNews = 0
```

Comment: the HEADER_LIST is on the top right hand side, starting with "WAS GIBT'S NEUES?" The command you mentioned is already in my typoscript.